# Php mail not sending

Tags: php, email

I'm trying to send an email using php but it's not working..
 This is my code:

```
<form method="post" name="contact" action="#contact">
                        <div class="left">
                            <label for="author">Name:</label> <input name="nom" type="text" class="input_field" id="author" maxlength="40" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="right">                           
                            <label for="email">Email:</label> <input name="email" type="text" class="input_field" id="email" maxlength="40" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <label for="text">Message:</label> <textarea id="text" name="text" rows="0" cols="0"></textarea>
                        <input type="submit" class="submit_btn float_l" name="submit" id="submit" value="Send" />
                    </form>
                    <?php
                    $name= ($_POST["nom"]);
                    $mail= ($_POST["email"]);
                    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
                    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
                    $headers .= 'From:<nelson-book@outlook.fr>' . "\r\n";
                    $suject="Book";
                    $message = "Nom: <br/>" .$name. "email:<br/> " .$email. "message: " .$_POST["text"];
                    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
      mail("nelson-book@outlook.fr", $suject, $message, $headers);
      echo" teste";


}

?>
```

I already used a code SUPER similar to this ant it totally worked.. Can the problem be from the server?
thanks in advance.

Comment: is teste being echoed on screen?

Comment: your script is correct check your server mail settings......

Answer (score 1):

check out your SMTP server restriction when you send email, with another hosting domain like, "outlook.fr", somethime this is't allowed.